# Call to a member function add_item() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have been having trouble with getting my PHP Cart to work, every time I go to add a product I always encounter an error which has been shown in the title.

```
 <?php

 $cart->add_item($new_item);

 ?>
```

That's the line of code where the error has been coming up, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us a bit more code. The error clearly says, that `$cart` is not an object. Also see: see [ask] and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Either you do not successfully create an object which is to be referenced by $cart, or it is overwritten.

Comment: You can use var_dump($cart) and see what is $cart.

Answer (score 1):

`$cart` is non object, maybe `$cart` is null in your case